# Converting inheriting models to View Models

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, viewmodel

I got a solution consisting of multiple projects.
One of the projects contains the Models.
Another contains (and uses) ViewModels.

To convert models to view models I would usually write an extension method in the VM project, something like this:

```
public static BananaVm ToVm(this Banana model)
{
   BananaVm vm = new BananaVm();
   vm.Taste = model.Taste;
   return vm;
}
```

However in my project, the Banana model inherits from the Fruit model and in my VM project I receive a fruit.

Therefore I'm not able to call fruit.ToVm() unless I get the type of the fruit first and cast it to that before calling .ToVm() as shown below:

```
var vm = ((Banana)fruit).ToVm();
```

Seeing as I got multiple different fruits, I'll right now have to use a switch to first find the correct type and then cast the fruit to the type after which I can call .ToVm() - for example:

```
Fruit fruit = FruitService.GetAFruit();
switch(fruit.GetType().Name)
{
   case "Banana":
      return ((Banana)fruit).ToVm();
   case "Orange":
      etc...
}
```

The switch statement which I feel forced to use doesn't seem like a good practice to me (I got over 20 different fruits, thus over 20 cases would be needed).

Does anyone have a better solution which could avoid the switch statement?

*Note that I can't add a .ToVm method in the fruit classes themselves as only the Vm project has a reference to the Model project.*

Comment: Looks like a good place to use the ["Factory method pattern"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern#C.23).

Comment: @SuperOli
I've looked it over and I'm pretty sure I understand the factory pattern but I don't quite see how it solves my issue. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Why don't you create a VM for Fruit? 
public static FruitVm ToVm(this Fruit model){};

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I didn't want to reply back in the comments since I had a bit of code.

At my workplace, we use the following in a couple of places and we never had any issues with it:

```
public class Factory
{
    public static FruitVM GetFruitVM(Fruit fruit)
    {
        if (fruit == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fruit");

        if (fruit is Banana)
            return new BananaVM((Banana)fruit);
        if (fruit is Orange)
            return new OrangeVM((Orange)fruit);

        throw new NotImplementedException(string.Format("The Factory doesn't carry this fruit {0}!", fruit.ToString()));
    }
}

// Usage example
Banana banana = GetBananaModelSomehow();
FruitVM fruitVM = Factory.GetFruitVM(banana);
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for, but like I said earlier, we've been using this pattern for a few years now and it's fine for us.